# ESP32 HTTP Server request interrupts Telnet session

Tags: esp32, web-server, http, tcpip

I have an ESP32 application that uses a web server as a user interface. For auditing and debugging during development I use Serial; however, that is impractical in the installed system. So, I decided to use Telnet (TCP/IP) to monitor what is happening when Serial is impractical.

The issue is that once a TCP/IP session has been established, when a HTTP request is received, the TCP/IP session is aborted.

I have reproduced the issue in a minimal sketch here:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WebServer.h>

WiFiClient telnetClient;
WebServer server(80);
WiFiServer telnetServer(23);

void telnetPrint(const char* text)
{
  if (telnetClient)
  {
    telnetClient.print(text);
  }
}

void telnetPrintln(const char *text)
{
  telnetPrint(text);
  telnetPrint("\r\n");
}

void _print(const char* text)
{
  Serial.print(text);
  telnetPrint(text);
}

void _println(const char* text)
{
  Serial.println(text);
  telnetPrintln(text);
}

void _println(IPAddress myIP)
{
  char rgIPTxt[32];
  sprintf(rgIPTxt,"%u.%u.%u.%u",myIP[0],myIP[1],myIP[2],myIP[3]);
  _println(rgIPTxt);
}

const char *rootFmt="\
<html>\
  <head>\
    <title>Test</title>\
  </head>\
  <body>\
    <h1>Test</h1>\
    <div>\
      <h2>Heap size=%d<br><br>\
    </div>\
  </body>\
</html>\
";

char rootMessage[1024];

void updateRootMessage()
{
  _println("updateRoot");
  snprintf(rootMessage, sizeof(rootMessage), rootFmt,
           heap_caps_get_free_size(MALLOC_CAP_8BIT)
           );
}

void handleRoot() 
{
  _println("Entered handleRoot");
  updateRootMessage();
  server.send(200, "text/html", rootMessage);
  _println("Leaving handleRoot");
}

void wifiSTASetup(const char*ssid, const char*password)
{
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  telnetServer.begin();
  telnetClient=telnetServer.available();
  _println("");

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    delay(500);
    _print(".");
  }
  _println("");
  _print("Connected to ");
  _println(ssid);
  _print("IP address: ");
  _println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.begin();
}

#define BAND    915E6

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  wifiSTASetup("your ssid", "your password");
}

void loop() 
{
  server.handleClient();
  if (!telnetClient)
  {
    telnetClient=telnetServer.available();
    if (telnetClient)
    {
      _println("telnetClient obtained");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: create an issue https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues

Comment: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/4399